# Clear screen on mac Os X

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, std

I am using c++ on Qt creator. I look for a command to clean screen.

I tried `system("CLS") and system("clear")` but it did not work

I try

```
 #include <curses.h>
    clear();
    refresh();
```

I got this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_clear", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

[From the source page:] The Curses library is designed for working with the console. Advantages: it is cross-platform. Disadvantages: it doesn't interact well with the standard streams. In other words, you shouldn't mix printf() and the like or cout and the like with Curses. Use Standard I/O or Curses, but not both. (You can still employ Standard I/O with things other than the terminal, of course.)

```
#include <curses.h>

.
.
clear();
refresh(); // changes will appear on the screen after you call refresh()
```

You should get the NCurses distribution from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)

To use the curses library, you need to link your project with it. In the project file (.pro), add the following line:[@KubaOber]

```
LIBS += -lcurses
```

[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/#UsingCurses)

Comment: You do not address the asker's issue, namely that the curses library is not linked into the target.

Comment: I didn't know the answer to linking problem. But that issue arose after providing the initial solution to use curses library!

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a "screen" only applies if you're doing a console application.

To use the curses library, you need to link your project with it. In the project file (`.pro`), add the following line:

```
LIBS += -lcurses
```